# Problem regarding ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 upgradation

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager, source, partial-upgrade

After I started the upgradation, The steps like downloading the new packages, installing the new packages went well without any error. After that step, My software update app got freezed and it remained freezed for like 2 hours almost. Then I force restarted my system with restart button. But after restart, it was Ubuntu 18.04. So I'm not sure if the upgradation was completed successfully or not. My files are safe afer the restart. But how can I be sure that everything is okay. Can anyone please help me about this matter?

My /etc/apt/sources.list looks like

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted multiverse universe
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which method did you use to release-upgrade?   `do-release-upgrade`, `update-manager-core` or other?  I would login via terminal and `sudo apt update` to validate the sources are read correctly (watching the output), then possibly `sudo apt dist-upgrade` in hopes of continue, but this step would possibly vary on what method you used to release-upgrade.

Comment: I used software updater to check whether my system is up to date or not. Then it says that your system is up to date and asks if I want to upgrade my system from 16.04 to 18.04. I selected the upgrade option and followed the instruction to upgrade it and the aforementioned problem happened. The sources.list is of my present system (18.04).

Comment: Your `sources.list` does not fill me with confidence, because it looks modified; there should be loads of instructions in the form of comments there.  Regardless I'd do what I said (`sudo apt update` which is mostly to ensure the output looks correct), then `sudo apt dist-upgrade` in the hopes it would upgrade any packages not upgraded.  Reset button I take as being a power-button  (did the magic SysRq not work? or were they not tried?  even if you don't remember the keystrokes, it's worth it to use another device to look up how to use them when necessary)

Comment: The result of `sudo apt update` is giving an error like

`W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 5A7D1D38BEB6D886 home:Horst3180 OBS Project <home:Horst3180@build.opensuse.org>
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Comment: The result of `sudo apt dist-upgrade` went well without error. I'm also worried about the `sources.list` . I used the restart button ( there is a small button on cpu of my desktop, just bellow the power button to force restart the system). So what should I do at this point to be sure everything is okay?

Comment: That is not an official source (a clue being opensuse is not Ubuntu!) which should have been removed before you release-upgraded.  If you add unusual sources, you should remember to remove them before release-upgrade & like steps. Are you using Ubuntu?  (your sources don't match Ubuntu & look 'created' - I'd suggest cleaning them)

Comment: Of course, I'm using Ubuntu. Yes I should have removed that. I'm actually very new to Ubuntu. Anyway I did the `sudo apt update` after removing that , it went without any error. So what should I do at this point? How can I be sure? Please help .
Thank you.

Comment: As I understood it you have completed `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.   Since you have run `sudo apt update` again, I would `sudo apt dist-upgrade` again (expecting nothing to be done), then reboot & test your system.  Next time, all unofficial sources should be removed before you release-upgrade (or bump versions); ideally the software from those sources should be removed as well, but I usually skip this step [*i do however consider whatever I added from unusual sources to guess how it may impact, which will be [very] hard for a newcomer; i leave comments in my sources.list when I change things*].

Comment: Yes I did complete `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and rebooted my system. But what should I do to test if my system is okay? 
Thanks for the advice. I will keep it in my mind.

Comment: Use it normally to test. Ensure the programs you rely on work as expected, some of them may be later versions, so may involve some change, but you don't want regressions (ie. something that used to work no longer does). Testing may involve a few days of use, which in the end you'll decide it's fine, better, or more likely some things better & a couple meh (different). If it's a desktop, Ubuntu 16.04 used Unity, your 18.04 I think will have Unity and GNOME (selected at login). I use flavors so aren't sure how that upgrade step was.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc for your time. I'll let you know if something comes up.

Comment: One thing, I would like to mention here, is that my Firefox tabs (Sometimes the whole Firefox) are crashing frequently. Is it something to worry about? What should I do?

Comment: 16.04 to 18.04 was a long time ago for me; this machine runs 19.10 (testing) so I forget what changes occurred during that step. Me (in your position) I'd [normally] probably remove add-ons; check I didn't have two versions installed (work out what I had installed, snap? deb? etc official or unofficial source?[*mandatory if this*]) then re-construct my setup.  Because of the recent firefox-stuff-up (certificate expiry) you're in an unusual situation with add-ons (fixed with a 'survey'-hack).  ie. *I would probably do a quick re-survey of where firefox is (certificate wise) & rebuild*

Comment: hi @guiverc , I just wanted to inform you that my desktop is crashing very frequently and and its going to the login page. It happens especially I try to use Firefox or Chrome. What should I do? If I try upgrading my system to Ubuntu 18.10, will solve my problem? how stable is the version 18.04( if you have used it) ?

Comment: It's up to you.  If my system isn't stable I tend to re-install.  This box I'm using is dual boot,; the 19.10 I usually use, and a 18.04 LTS that I'm considering re-install (in your case I'd do it).  For me that's an extra backup of anything I don't want to lose, install using 'something-else' and ensure I don't format anything. It notes your added programs, wipes system directories, installs, then adds back your added programs (if from Ubuntu repos) but doesn't touch my user data (as long as I don't have format ticked).  This tends to fix things far better than bumping to the next release.

Comment: Most people find Ubuntu 18.04 LTS very stable.  Most reviews I can think of say the 'improvements' in 18.10 weren't worth the upgrade; even with 19.04 (gnome) being faster reviews generally say it's not worth it. As stated I primarily use flavors (XFCE [xubuntu] & LXQt [lubuntu], but I do know if gnome crashes you're returned to the login screen (extensions are usually to blame; but if you haven't added any it should be good; I can't speak to Unity on 18.04).  I would really consider a re-install of 18.04 (something else & no-format of partitions, but backup first) if I was in your shoes.